# Help understanding Keychain passwords vs Safari passwords

Tags: mojave, password

I don't understand by which criteria a password is saved to Keychain vs Safari. Can I select somewhere where the passwords will be saved?
Let's say that I want all my passwords to be kept in Keychain, how to?

Thank you

Comment: I am pretty positive that Safari passwords are stored on the keychain.  and with keychain syncing(iCloud keychain) . it allows all your devices to have the same password repository(credit cards too).

Comment: Why do you think that the safari passwords are not all saved to key chain?

Answer (score 3):

Like Tik27 said, when Safari saves a password it is saving it to the Mac Keychain. There is no way for Safari to actually save a password, it hands it off to the keychain.

So any time Safari (or Mail.app, Finder, etc.) offers to save a password it is being saved in the keychain.

you can verify this by signing on to a new website with a username and password, letting Safari prompt you to save the password and then opening Keychain.app and seeing the new username/password saved there with a date/time stamp of only minutes ago.

Comment: Hi Steve, my question was related to the fact that i cannot find one password present in Safari Passwords but not in Mac Keychain. I did the recommended test and the password was saved both in Safari Passwords as well in Keychain. So I don't know what previously happened...  Thanks!                                              BTW: I have the iCloud switched off, but this should have no impact except on sync between devices.